# how to make progress bar go back on click with go back button

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I'd like to click go back button and make the progress bar go back a step

```
function progress(){
var totalQuestions = 7;
var currentQuestion = 0;
var $progressbar = $("#progressbar");

$(".option").on("click", function(){
  if (currentQuestion >= totalQuestions){ return; }
  currentQuestion++;
  $progressbar.css("width", Math.round(100 * currentQuestion / totalQuestions) + "%");
});

}
```

Go back button is taking me to previous questions but is not changing progress bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess this could help with a button with class of `backward`:

```
function progress(){
var totalQuestions = 7;
var currentQuestion = 0;
var FinalCurrentQuestion = 0;
var $progressbar = $("#progressbar");

$(".option").on("click", function(){
  if (currentQuestion >= totalQuestions){ return; }
  currentQuestion++;
  FinalCurrentQuestion = currentQuestion;
  $progressbar.css("width", Math.round(100 * currentQuestion / totalQuestions) + "%");
});

$(".backward").on("click", function(){
  if (FinalCurrentQuestion == currentQuestion) {
  currentQuestion--;
  $progressbar.css("width", Math.round(100 * currentQuestion / totalQuestions) + "%");
  }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra button on the page with an id of, for example, backButton you can do this:

```
$(".backButton").on("click", function(){
  currentQuestion--;
  $progressbar.css("width", Math.round(100 * currentQuestion / totalQuestions) + "%");
});
```

So you add an extra onClickListener to a different button which controls the same progressbar as you can put it in the exact same function and you declared the variables globally in the function.

Comment: Daniel Vercouteren thank you for your reply. This solution makes progress bar goo all the way to the start, my goal is to go back one step